# Cube to Sphere mapping (inverse function wanted)

Tags: math, glsl, shader

I've came across a cube to sphere mapping function that provides a more uniform result than just normalizing the coordinates or other mapping methods. Unfortunately there is no unwrapping function.

Source: http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html

```
vec3 spherify ( vec3 v ) {
    float x2 = v.x * v.x;
    float y2 = v.y * v.y;
    float z2 = v.z * v.z;
    vec3 s;
    s.x = v.x * sqrt(1.0 - y2 / 2.0 - z2 / 2.0 + y2 * z2 / 3.0);
    s.y = v.y * sqrt(1.0 - x2 / 2.0 - z2 / 2.0 + x2 * z2 / 3.0);
    s.z = v.z * sqrt(1.0 - x2 / 2.0 - y2 / 2.0 + x2 * y2 / 3.0);
    return s;
}
```

How could this be unwrapped back to a cube face? To wrap back to a square i use the following, though it doesn't unwrap the special squeezing of the coordinates.

```
vec3 cubify ( vec3 s ) {
    
    s.x = ( s.x / s.z );
    s.y = ( s.y / s.z );
    
    return s;
}
```

Which looks as the following
[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz9SS.png)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Mapping A Sphere To A Cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656899/mapping-a-sphere-to-a-cube). There is an answer there for how to do the inverse mapping, but be warned it is tricky. =)

Comment: Oh! I came across this question but the unwrapping function cubify doesn't seem to work, it creates a very wrong result unfortunately. I tried double check by copying the exact same code of that answer again but somehow, even though there is literally no difference WebGL keeps throwing me a imaginary syntax error "ERROR: 1:1: '' : syntax error" if that function is added to the code, which clearly isn't even at 1:1 with a empty quote?

Comment: Wait, i figured out what's wrong, somehow the code on the answer had special characters as minus symbol, that breaks the compiler it seems. Anyway it almost worked, mayor part is correctly wrapped back, though at the left and right middle corners some squares are not existing, like there is a zero division or something, is this penetrating precision a lot? I've read in the comments something regarding precision too.

Comment: Okay i figured out the problem here too, when the cube is divided symmetrically this unwrapping method doesn't seem to work along x axis if y is zero. Anyway thanks for the hint, not sure why the version i had was different.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this (C++/VCL):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
#include "glsl_math.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
const int n=10*10*6;
vec3 col[n];
vec3 cube[n];
vec3 sphere[n];
vec3 cube2[n];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 spherify(vec3 v)
    {
    float x2 = v.x * v.x;
    float y2 = v.y * v.y;
    float z2 = v.z * v.z;
    vec3 s;
    s.x = v.x * sqrt(1.0 - y2 / 2.0 - z2 / 2.0 + y2 * z2 / 3.0);
    s.y = v.y * sqrt(1.0 - x2 / 2.0 - z2 / 2.0 + x2 * z2 / 3.0);
    s.z = v.z * sqrt(1.0 - x2 / 2.0 - y2 / 2.0 + x2 * y2 / 3.0);
    return s;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
vec3 cubify(vec3 v)
    {
    int i;
    float r,a;
    // major axis and size
    a=fabs(v.x);         { r=a; i=0; }
    a=fabs(v.y); if (r<a){ r=a; i=1; }
    a=fabs(v.z); if (r<a){ r=a; i=2; }
    v/=r; r*=1.75; a=4.0*r/M_PI;
    // convert of cube + linearization
         if (i==0){ v.y=a*atan(v.y/r); v.z=a*atan(v.z/r); }
    else if (i==1){ v.x=a*atan(v.x/r); v.z=a*atan(v.z/r); }
    else          { v.x=a*atan(v.x/r); v.y=a*atan(v.y/r); }
    // just remedy boundaries after linearization
    if (v.x<-1.0) v.x=-1.0;
    if (v.x>+1.0) v.x=+1.0;
    if (v.y<-1.0) v.y=-1.0;
    if (v.y>+1.0) v.y=+1.0;
    if (v.z<-1.0) v.z=-1.0;
    if (v.z>+1.0) v.z=+1.0;
    return v;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void set_cube()
    {
    float u,v,d;
    int m=sqrt(n/6),i,j,k;
    k=0; d=2.0/float(m-1);
    for (u=-1.0,i=0;i<m;i++,u+=d)
     for (v=-1.0,j=0;j<m;j++,v+=d)
        {
        col[k]=vec3(0.5,0.0,0.0); cube[k]=vec3(u,v,-1.0); k++;
        col[k]=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0); cube[k]=vec3(u,v,+1.0); k++;
        col[k]=vec3(0.0,0.5,0.0); cube[k]=vec3(u,-1.0,v); k++;
        col[k]=vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0); cube[k]=vec3(u,+1.0,v); k++;
        col[k]=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.5); cube[k]=vec3(-1.0,u,v); k++;
        col[k]=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0); cube[k]=vec3(+1.0,u,v); k++;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.5);
    glRotatef(-10.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(-20.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    int i;

    glPointSize(2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(-3.0,0.0,0.0); glBegin(GL_POINTS); for (i=0;i<n;i++){ glColor3fv(col[i].dat); glVertex3fv(cube[i].dat); } glEnd();     // set_cube
    glTranslatef(+3.0,0.0,0.0); glBegin(GL_POINTS); for (i=0;i<n;i++){ glColor3fv(col[i].dat); glVertex3fv(sphere[i].dat); } glEnd();   // spherify
    glTranslatef(+3.0,0.0,0.0); glBegin(GL_POINTS); for (i=0;i<n;i++){ glColor3fv(col[i].dat); glVertex3fv(cube2[i].dat); } glEnd();    // cubify

    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gl_init(Handle);
    int i;
    set_cube();
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) sphere[i]=spherify(cube[i]);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)  cube2[i]=cubify(sphere[i]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just ignore the VCL stuff. Code creates uniform grid `cube` points using `set_cube` , that is converted into `sphere` using your `spherify` and that is finally converted to `cube2` using mine `cubify`.

Here preview:

[image: preview]

from left `cube,sphere,cube2`. The colors are stored in `col` to better show the mapping between points...

The idea behind `cubify` is to leave biggest coordinate as is and the other two convert into spherical angle and then use this angle as coordinate. Basically its a reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62754601/2521214). Its a bit nonlinear near edges hence the slight shifting of 45 deg range to smaller ones... Also to avoid crossings of points above surface after linearization another check is involved (the 6 ifs at the end).